# Angular 5 Casting back ElementRef to Component

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to cast back `ElementRef` to a component.
I have a situation where I have in my hand the `nativeElement` and I need to cast it to a component.
Have a look at the console.log, I want to extract the `name`, Can I cast it back?
Thanks
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8aoq7f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<sub-component [name]="'test'"></sub-component>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
 constructor(private ref : ElementRef){
    console.log((<SubComponent>this.ref.nativeElement).name); //<--- .name is undefined
 }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'sub-component',
  template: `<div>{{name}}</div>`,
})
export class SubComponent  {
  @Input() name : string
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont' have to cast an element to a component. Just use viewchild

```
import { Component,Input,ElementRef,ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sub-component',
  template: `<div>{{name}}</div>`,
})
export class SubComponent  {
  @Input() name : string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<sub-component [name]="'test'"></sub-component>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild(SubComponent) private subComponent: SubComponent;

 constructor(){}

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.subComponent.name); // No longer undefined
 }
}
```

working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axtulh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I have asked, I have a native element in my hand, and I want to cast it back to a component. I used view child just to grab the native element for the sake of the example.

Comment: So, Is it possible to cast from native element / Dom element back to component?

Comment: No. You cannot, because you can't convert an HTML Element into a TypeScript class. That's why you must use something like ViewChild

Comment: i'm in directive and getting elementref, so i can not use viewchild, any suggestion?

Comment: The questions asks how to cast an ElementRef to a specific component. This doesn't answer that question.

Answer (score 5):

answer to

> i'm in directive and getting elementref, so i can not use viewchild,
>   any suggestion?

can be found here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277.

```
...
    constructor(
         @Host() @Self() @Optional() public hostCheckboxComponent : MdlCheckboxComponent
        ,@Host() @Self() @Optional() public hostSliderComponent   : MdlSliderComponent
    ){
                if(this.hostCheckboxComponent) {
                       console.log("host is a checkbox");
                } else if(this.hostSliderComponent) {
                       console.log("host is a slider");
                }
         }
...
```

In your case you can only use
`@Host() @Self() public myComponent : MyComponent`

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party but I had the same need.  It turns out there is a ng globals that contains helper functions:

`ng.getComponent<T>(element: Element): T | null`

https://angular.io/api/core/global/ngGetComponent

this ng is stored in the window object.

```
window.ng.getComponent(myElem) as MySampleComponent;
```

Comment: Not downvoting but this solution only works for testing/debug mode (not in Production), see @Flo's answer below

Answer (score 1):

I'm later :-)

The only way is the `@ViewChild()` way. The official docs says to window.ng
functions:

> Exposes a set of functions in the global namespace which are useful
> for debugging the current state of your application. These functions
> are exposed via the global ng "namespace" variable automatically when
> you import from @angular/core and run your application in development
> mode. These functions are not exposed when the application runs in a
> production mode.

Here is the link: [Angular Global Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/global)

So the window.ng.getComponent() and all other window.ng functions will not working in a production build. These functions are made for debugging, testing und developing.

Greetings, Florian