# Get Angular component class from DOM element

Tags: angular

I believe the answer to this is "no", but is there a method/service in Angular where I can pass in a component's root DOM node (e.g. `<foo-component>`) and receive the component instance (e.g. `FooComponent`)?

I couldn't find an associated SO post on this.

Example:

```
<foo-component id="foo"></foo-component>

const fooElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('foo');
const fooInstance: FooComponent = getInstanceFromElement(fooElement);
```

Is there a method in Angular like `getInstanceFromElement`?

**Edit:**

I can't use `ViewChild`... I'm looking for a global service I can use. Suppose I am not invoking this method from the component class. I'm well acquainted with `ViewChild`/`ContentChild` and they are not what I'm looking for. Suppose I am in a globally injected service and am trying to do something like the following:

```
class MyService {
  constructor() {}

  getInstanceFromElement(element: HTMLElement): Component<T> {
    // Is there some special helper service I can use here?
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the component DOM node? Why can't you get the component instance directly (e.g. with a template reference variable)?

Comment: Suppose it's just not feasible to add template references, and that I just have access to a DOM node.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for ViewChild?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640307/angular-5-casting-back-elementref-to-component

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. `@ViewChild()` was the right hint here. Let me give you an example:

```
@ViewChild('editorStepsDomElements', { static: false, read: ElementRef }) fooComponentDomElement: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('fooComponent', { static: false, read: FooComponent }) fooComponent: FooComponent;
```

So basically you can define in the `ViewChild()` what you want to get. Just set the `read` parameter to either `ElementRef` (for getting the DOM element), or to the respective component you want to get.

Comment: OP says he can't use ViewChild

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p9o3ek?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Template:

```
<foo-component #foo></foo-component>
```

TS:

```
  @ViewChild('foo', { static: false }) fooComponent: FooComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.fooComponent)
  }
```

Comment: OP says he can't use ViewChild

Comment: @devpato He said it 3 hours back and i answered this 5 days back

Comment: I know. I'm letting you know for you to update the answer and people to stop up voting an answer that is not correct based on the OP requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can do with Dynamic Component Loader to attach a component dynamically to the DOM. Follow this [link](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do. I added a code snippet to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

This is simple in Angular. `@ViewChild`/`@ViewChildren` and `@ContentChild`/`@ContentChildren` return the component reference/`QueryList<Component>` by default during the `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngAfterContentInit` lifecycles.

For Example:

```
@Component({
  template:`<foo-component></foo-component>`
})
export TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(FooComponent, { static: false }) fooComponent: FooComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.fooComponent)
  }
```

For directives, you can use a template variable if the directive specifies an `exportAs`. See https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26 for a good write up.